# How to show alert and refresh page simultaneously after response from Firebase?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently I am using firebase to store data and as soon as I get response from firebase, I need to show alert and refresh form page. Here is the code I am using for the purpose:

```
  // Push a new inquiry to the database using those values
  inquiry.push({
    "name": name,
    "contact": contact,
    "email": email,
    "board": board,
    "subject": subject,
    "standard": standard,
    "message": message,
  }).then(() => {
    alert("Thank You! Your request has been received and our team will connect with you shortly.");
});
```

But the problem here is either the alert is shown OR the page is being refreshed. Both are not working simultaneously. So, my question here is how to show alert and refresh the form page one after another?

Comment: Can you show the current behavior?

Comment: Currently it is showing alert but not refreshing the page.

Comment: Is this real time database?

Comment: yes it is real time DB

Comment: Do you want to refresh the list existing list or just need to clar filled data by enduser?

Comment: just clear the data and show popup

Comment: Can you show, how you are taking values from HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `alert` function is a blocking function. This means that when you run:

```js
alert("hello"); 
console.log("hello again");
```

If you try it, you'll see that the `hello again` won't be logged, until you've pressed ok in the alert popup.

This means that you can just put the code that navigates after the `alert` in your `then()`:

```
// Push a new inquiry to the database using those values
inquiry.push({
  "name": name,
  "contact": contact,
  "email": email,
  "board": board,
  "subject": subject,
  "standard": standard,
  "message": message,
}).then(() => {
  alert("Thank You! Your request has been received and our team will connect with you shortly.");
  location.reload();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one, if user click `ok` in alert, window will reload:

```
if(!alert("Thank You! Your request has been received and our team will connect with you shortly.")){
  window.location.reload();
}
```

Comment: tried this code but it is not showing popup even. .then(() => {
    alert("Thank You! Your request has been received and our team will connect with you shortly.");
      if(!alert("Thank You! Your request has been received and our team will connect with you shortly.")){window.location.reload();}
  });

Comment: @nikksindia without call alert twicely

Comment: @nikksindia please try this one `if(confirm('your message')){ window.location.reload();  }`, don't understand thy alert doesn't work, also i understand that you probably don't need a cancel button